# Display inline block hover

Tags: html, css

I am using `display: inline-block;` to keep some div's next to each other. I do not know why but on hover the div will move up. I think the amount it moves up has to do with the padding of an element in its non hover form(The .title class element). This is very odd and I cannot figure out why this is happening because all values are reset in the hover form.
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m99u/) 
*Note I'm using Sass so the css might look a bit weird*

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.option` - http://jsfiddle.net/6m99u/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.option {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Because you declare the elements `inline`, they follow the same vertical alignment rules as all flowing content of a page - sort of centered. Force it to a fixed position of the entire line and it's solved.

Comment: Ty. I spent forever trying to figure out why.

Comment: Added a bit of explanation too  :P

Answer (score 0):

Adding the above line to the element I wanted to hover helped me solve this problem:

```css
.example {
border: 10px solid transparent;
}

.example :hover{
border: 10px solid;
}
```